# Application loader stuck at the stage of “Verifying assets with the iTunes Store”

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I was about to upload an app to iTunes connect, but the application loader has been stuck at the stage of "Verifying assets with the iTunes Store" and pending for almost an hour. Network is fine and I have never seen this before.Has anybody encountered this kind of issue? what is the solution?thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Cancel the process and retry. If the problem persists you might want to do it via Xcode instead of ApplicationLoader. Don't forget to open an issue with Apple to let them know, after restarting AL, your Mac and reinstalling AL to make sure it can't be fixed.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks:) That strategy worked. I restarted my computer and started the uploading process again and it worked.

Answer (score 48):

This issue is predominantly on enterprise networks. There are a number of solutions please note that some of these are mere repetition of the above.

**1. Make sure no pending contracts are waiting to be signed/accepted**

Go to [member center](http://developer.apple.com/account/) and make sure all contracts are signed, pending contracts will be highlighted in a big yellow/red banner at the top of the page

**2.Change networks**

Get off your enterprise network and tether to your cell phone (slower but works). Your home network should also work if you've not fiddled with your router

**3. Get off your proxy**

Change or preferably switch off your proxy. If Charles or similar apps are running, switch them off as well.

**4. Use the standalone Application Loader app**

This is only a walk around as it allows you to toggle the protocols. Removing Signiant & Aspera protocols works for me even in office network.

[image]

Application loader can be found under Xcode -> Open Deleveloper Tool -> Application Loader

[image]

**5. Automate it!**

Use FastLane tools, but remember to set     `ENV["DELIVER_ITMSTRANSPORTER_ADDITIONAL_UPLOAD_PARAMETERS"] = "-t DAV"` within your configuration file.

This is a lot more work than the other steps above, but provides a lasting solution. Fastlane is also really cool if you configure it correctly.

**6. Cry**

Because developers have bad days too.

Comment: Thanks a lot #4 did it for me. I was at the library and I guess they have retricted internet. jsut had to untick signiant and aspera

Comment: #4 is pure gold

Comment: Just this solution (Signiant, Aspera) worked for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: 4 was my solution but removed in XCode 11. :/

Comment: This answer is also valid for 'Transporter' (new version of Application Loader)

Answer (score 11):

**I recommend not to cancel.**

The process seems to be stuck, but for my part waiting for 10-15 minutes finished with upload success.

Cancelling will most likely result in builds on iTunes Connect that will never finish processing. They will only be removed by iTunes Connect internal auto-cleanup after approx. 15-30 days. The downside is that it is not possible to use any build for that version number for internal testing in iTunes Connect as the indefinitely processing build version is the only one listed to choose from. The only way around is increasing the build number and you can choose it for external testing.

Comment: agree with this, i had the same thing

Comment: i don't know; i must have cancelled a 100 times, never resulted in a processing build.

Comment: Mine took 10 minutes on my corporate network. Takes about 45 seconds tethered to an LTE device off network.

Answer (score 10):

I develop apps for a company that has rather tight security constraints.  I had this same issue trying to publish from behind the firewall so I got on the phone with our networking guy and sure enough there is an SSH connection to Apple that opens up to upload the app. While it makes perfect sense to secure your livelihood in transit using a SSH tunnel, to a set of security rules on a firewall it can raise flags.

If you try everything and you are publishing from within a business, consider checking the security constraints to see if you your access to Apple for that final upload isn't being blocked by default.

Answer (score 8):

I was running into this, and tried all the above suggestions with no success. I then realized my app's state in iTunes Connect was in "Developer Rejected".

I removed the build I had submitted / rejected, which put the app back into the "Ready for Upload" state.

I was then able to get passed the "Verifying Assets" step.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wau wtf how we are supposed to get this , on SO ? Thanks !

Comment: This is another bug of apple that is being ignored as they just don't care about developers...

Answer (score 7):

I found this to be an issue when using free Wi-Fi from a retailer. i.e Starbucks. I was in an area where I could 6 different networks from local stores and the all hung at this stage from both Application Loader and xCode.

Don't waste your time! Join either your own network or one where you can speak with the admin. Retail Wi-Fi's lead to the dark side.

Answer (score 7):

**Every single time** this "freeze" happens, I can fix it by going to developer.apple.com in Safari and logging in.

Magically the upload resumes after doing that. Not a co-incidence. I think it's a long standing bug where Xcode somehow loses authorization.

Comment: yeah, that magic just happened with me as well! kudos @martinjbaker

Answer (score 6):

I have the same problem when I trying upload from my corporate network, but I just share mobile internet and use it, everything loading fast and without problem.

Comment: This is precisely the solution that I use every time! Tethering has been a solution to more than just one issue for me...

Comment: Tethering all the way!

Answer (score 5):

The main cause for me was Review and accept new terms in the member center! Sometimes too tis a matter of unblocking https ports and removing any https proxies.

Answer (score 4):

Change the wifi solved it for me

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I revoked the "IOS development" and "IOS distribution" profiles, and re-create them inside Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts -> View Details

Answer (score 2):

This is a permanent issue at one of the places where I work from. And the issue is not in Provisioning at all in my case.

So, I tried to check what happens using Wireshark: I see correctly initiated SSL connection, data starts to be uploaded via UDP, but then "Retransmission" or "Spurious Retransmission" messages start happening and it all ends up either in "Destination unreachable (Port unreachable)" or connection gets reset by either side. Sometimes it happens after 2-3 seconds and sometimes in less than 1 second. Organizer tries again, but not always. Sometimes it just stops and waits for an unknown amount of time.

What I have tried:

- [fail] Restarting computer or WiFi
- [fail] waiting for several hours hoping the process will finish
- [fail] fixing clock on WiFi router (automatic clock was turned off)
- [**sometimes helps**] making several attempts in a row - this requires
  changing build number and re-archiving. Somewhat time-consuming.
- [**often helps**] finding another WiFi or using mobile network

I will continue playing with those router's settings and will update my answer if I find something.

Comment: Using another network really helps. My upload time is down to 2 minutes from an hour.

Answer (score 1):

for me, just switch internet connection from wifi to mobile data and its working fine

Answer (score 0):

I just needed a valid iOS Distribution provisioning profile. As soon as I created one it began the upload immediately.

Answer (score 0):

On Xcode 8.0 (8A218a), I was having this issue.

I had added the Associated Domains capability to handle Applinks. I had accidentally left a trailing '/' on my url. Removing this trailing slash fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Few things to check
1. make sure you have a valid distribution provisioning profile
2. your network blocking some request during the upload.

For me I had both the issues, 
after creating a valid profile, tried using my mobile hotspot and upload completed in 3 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

This may well be a coincidence, but I've found that I have to unplug all my devices for the upload to finish. I'm running Sierra in VMWare, which may or may not be related ... in any case, something easy to try if you're stuck!

Answer (score 0):

Had the fabric desktop app open. Closing that caused it to work right away.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your project is in "Prepare for Submission" on App Store Connect.

This happened to me as I already loaded a previous version of my app and found some new changes and was attempting to upload the new build. But the status on App Store Connect still said, "Waiting for Review". Rejecting the current build and changing the status to "Prepare for Submission" fixed the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I got this error, but surprisingly I got an email later that said processing was finished for the version I was attempting to upload so apparently it was a false alarm.