# stucked at Verifying assets with the iTunes Store

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, ipa

I am trying to upload the app.ipa to the iTune Connect. But it stcuked at Verifying assets with the iTunes Store step and it seems will never go further than that.

I search some other thread [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29494065/application-loader-stuck-at-the-stage-of-verifying-assets-with-the-itunes-store) But it does not solve my problem not matter how many times I tried. I wrote a bug to apple now. I dont know when it can be solved.

My Configuration:
Xcode 7.1.1 via stable network. itune connect status is preparing for submit.

Any solutions?

Comment: What error message(s) do you get?

Comment: @TheEye no error message, just stucked there forever

Comment: You can always try to use the application loader, or try a new test project to find out if it's a general problem with your environment or just with the specific project.