# Application Loader stuck at Verifying assets with the iTunes Store

Tags: ios, application-loader

I am trying to upload an ipa file (call it a.ipa) into iTunes Connect via application loader. While the uploading process pending at "Verifying assets with the iTunes Store" more than 8 hours. 
And validation for a.ipa is fine, uploaded another ipa also worked fine. Does anyone had the same issue? Or any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Fixed. My friend helped me submit and succeed. Seems caused by the network.

Comment: Possible solution[s] http://stackoverflow.com/a/42815259/1008984

Answer (score 2):

I've had this issue too. I was connected to a network that I think was blocking a needed port. When I disconnected from that network and tried another it worked.

Comment: But uploaded other ipa files were fine, so I guess is not my network or laptop issue?

Comment: That's what my issue was. Not sure what yours is exactly

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on our corporate network. The fix was to add proxy settings and disable the protocols that were being stopped by the proxy. If you know you have a proxy in the network path, edit the file :

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application\ Loader.app/Contents/MacOS/itms/java/lib/net.properties​
```

Place the following settings in the `net.properties` file, of course using **your** proxy hostname:

```
 http.proxyHost=proxy.example.com
 ​http.proxyPort=80
 ​http.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.*|[::1]|*.example.com
 ​https.proxyHost=proxy.example.com
 https.proxyPort=80
```

Then, go into the application loader's preferences screen and deselect all the protocols except anything that says DAV or WebDAV. This will ensure that HTTP/S is the only protocol attempted for connections.

Comment: Interesting. I will try this! Thank you.