# Unable to upload the ipa file to itunes store

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, apple-push-notifications, app-store-connect

I have renewed the developer account and after renewal revoked previous certificate and created new distribution certificate and provisioning profiles , but I am getting time remaining as infinity as in image below.

I have tried restart machine and Xcode but to no avail .

[image]

Comment: Why did you revoke?

Comment: before revoking also I tried but same issue was there so I tried after revoking .

Comment: Same problem was here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29494065/application-loader-stuck-at-the-stage-of-verifying-assets-with-the-itunes-store

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem too. After i accept new terms in member center issue has been resolved for me.

Comment: I think I have already accepted the terms otherwise the dialog appears at the top of developer.apple.com .

Comment: Wonderful. I had to add the contact information to get the upload working. Error message in Xcode was desperately useless !

Answer (score 0):

This happens at times when Xcode is not able to verify the assets.
The weird part is, xcode never times out on that request, however, application loader does. It goes into the state of verifying assets, and times out after a while, and continues uploading the build.

So try doing this ->

Click on the export button and export your app as an ipa file.

[image]

Once exported, open "Application Loader"

Log in there, Choose the IPA file from the exported folder and wait, it will go to verifying assets and then later it will upload your build.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Now the problem is solved , I think this is an Apple bug , It shows infinity but , if you keep itunesconnect in that condition for some time say around one hour, it will be uploaded successfully .