# Xcode freezes on "fetching app store configuration"

Tags: xcode, macos, app-store

I have mac os mojave and xcode Version 10.1 (10B61). I try build unity3D game. I can successfully build it to iphone 5S device. But when I try submit up to App Store it is not working.

What exactly happens:
On step "fetching app store configuration" xcode freezes. In active monitor I see it as unresponsible application (or something like it). And XCode take almost all free RAM (4.5GB). After sometime (around 20 minutes) mac restart (I have problem with iMac, it restart when use too much RAM, I don't think it related to xcode)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Application loader stuck at the stage of “Verifying assets with the iTunes Store”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29494065/application-loader-stuck-at-the-stage-of-verifying-assets-with-the-itunes-store)

Comment: It isn't a duplicate, but could be caused due to the same problem internally.. Only Apple can verify that. I have seen this on both Xcode 9 & Xcode 10.. But still there isn't a proper solution anywhere.


On Apple forums :

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/90294
https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/326145

Comment: Solved!! just leave it for 10 minutes eating all the RAM you've and it will finish .

Answer (score 5):

Actually, if I wait long enough (more then 15 minutes) it is start working. 
XCode require a lot of RAM + SWAP

Answer (score 4):

Here's an answer for someone who stumbles upon this later, I just want to share what helped me. I also ran into the same problem while trying to distribute a Unity-built game with Xcode (also contains pods).

I work on a MacBook Air 2013 with only 4GB of RAM, so whenever I do anything with Xcode, I first close everything other than Xcode, Finder and Activity Monitor. As soon as I start whatever it is that usually freezes Xcode, I switch to Activity Monitor and track what's happening with the memory.

In the case of freezing while "Fetching App Store Configuration...", the problem appeared to be RAM, more precisely SWAP. I did not have enough memory available on my hard drive, which Xcode tried to use for SWAP and just... well, failed. So I cleaned up my hard drive and finally it went through very smoothly, but it occupied about 9GB of RAM at its peak (5.4GB in SWAP).

So just try to have enough memory available to feed the beast, observe what's happening in Activity Monitor and you should be good.